# Save and display values of multiple checkboxes in WordPress

Tags: php, database, wordpress, checkbox, input

I am trying to save the value of multiple checkboxes in WordPress, So if a guest checks a checkbox (front-end) without clicking any submit buttons, this checked value will be stored in the database.

Next time anyone loads this page, this particular checkbox should be pre-checked.

So far I have got this code in the template file that is responsible for the content of the page I am trying to add these checkboxes to.

(This is no regular WP post/page template but a "collection page" generated by a WooCommerce collection plugin):

```
        //submit code 
      if(isset($_POST['cadeau'])  ){
          $data=serialize($_POST['cadeau']);

          update_post_meta($post_id, 'cadeau', $data);
      }

    //edit code

        $data=get_post_meta($post_id, 'cadeau');
        //$data=unserialize($data[0]);
        $data=$data[0];
        print_r($data);?> 

<input type="checkbox" name="cadeau[]" value="<?php echo $product_id;?>" <?php if(in_array($product_id,$data)  ){echo "checked";} ?> >
```

This is not working however.. Am I on the right track? Or am I doing it completely wrong?

Comment: How are you performing the post? If you print `$coll_id` what is the ID? Can you verify that it is being saved to the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, to make such things in WordPress (and not only) you have to make a POST request to the server. Either by submitting a form or doing an AJAX request. Here is an example of how to make it to work. If you don't want to make AJAX request just skip step 1 and jump directly to step 3 and have a look at the function. I am sure it will help you go on the right track.

**1.** Create a JS script which sends an AJAX request to *admin-ajax.php* file:

```
<script>
     jQuery("#submit-button").on("click", function(){
      var checkboxValue = jQuery("#your-checkbox").is(":checked") ? 1 : 0;
      jQuery.ajax({
          url: "http://www.yourdomain.com/admin-ajax.php",
          method: 'POST',
          data: {action: "save_checkbox", checked: checkboxValue}
      }).done(function(response){
          console.log("Response: " + response);
          //NOTE that 'action' MUST be the same as PHP function name you want to fire
          //you can do whatever you want here with your response
      }).fail(function(error){
          console.log(error);
      });
     })
  </script>
```

**2.** Create new file e.x. *myajax.php* and include it to *functions.php*
 **3.** Now write a function you want to fire on click, e.x.:

```
function save_checkbox(){
   $checkboxValue = $_REQUEST['checked'];

   update_post_meta($coll_id, 'cadeau', $checkboxValue );

   $response = array(
       "status" => "ok",
       "message" => "Post meta saved",
   );
   $response = json_encode($response);

   echo $response;

   die();
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_save_checkbox', 'save_checkbox' );
```

That's all. As I said note that `action`has to be the same as PHP function. If you want to have some response from your PHP function just `echo` it and this is what you will get as a response. If you'll get `0` as a response it means that function you want to fire does not exists or you didn't call `die()` at the end of your function. I hope I could help.